# How would I check if an array in another array contains x?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am coding chess and am wondering how I would check if an array in another array contains x.
It would work something like this:

`if(array contains array containing x)`

Comment: also can u give a sample array, it will be easier to help, because it could be different approach...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flat()` to monodimensionalize the array and `includes()` to check.

```js
let x = [0, 1, 2, [3, 4]];

if(x.flat(Infinity).includes(3)) {
  console.log("yes");
}
```

EDIT: Using `Infinity` as a parameter, as said in the comments, for multi-level arrays.

Comment: You should use `flat(Infinity)` for recursive flattening. It's generally a safer option if flattening of an entire parent array is needed.

Comment: While simple and elegant, doesn't necessarily work as intended. May give false positives if "3" is an item in the first array (change the "0" for a "3" and you get a positive hit outside the inside array). Could do a foreach on the base array, do an isArray, and from there flatten it and run includes perhaps? That would ensure it's only looking into arrays in the base array.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question you can do something like this

```js
const contains = (data, x) => data.some(d => d.includes(x))

const data1 = [
 [1],
 [2, 3, 4],
 [5]
]

console.log(contains(data1, 1), contains(data1,2), contains(data1, 7))
```

if you want a recursive approach you can do something like this

```js
const contains = (data, x) => {
  if(typeof data !== 'object'){
    return data === x
  }
  
  return data.some(d => contains(d, x))
}

const data1 = [
  [
    [1]
  ],
  [2],
  [[3, [4]]]
]

console.log(contains(data1, 1), contains(data1, 2),contains(data1, 3),contains(data1, 5))
```